# how to validate registration only if the user types something

Tags: javascript, registration

so that's what I'm trying to work with atm, but it doesn't work in the sense that when the user doesn't enter anything, he will get the "your phone number includes 10 numbers" alert although it should go straight into 'else' and display nothing & let him pass.
the point of this code is to validate the phone number only if the user actually types it, so that I won't get nonsense numbers in my database - but I'm not forcing the user to type in his number either.
the part that doesn't work is the if & else part. everything **inside** the 'if' works on its own, But I don't want to force users to type their phone number, so I added these if & else.

```js
function CheckPhone() {
        var x = document.getElementById("phone").value;
            if (x == "" || x.length > 0) {
                if (x == "" || x.length == 10) {
                    document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = "your phone number includes 10 numbers"
                    return false;
                }
                for (var s = 0; s < x.length; s++) {
                    if (!('0' <= x.charAt(s) && x.charAt(s) <= '9')) {
                        document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML =
                            "<span style='color:Red'>your phone number can only contain numbers</span>";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: What about international numbers? What about service numbers? It's not like I don't want to tell you how to solve this issue, but your entire approach is inherently wrong. You're going to run in a lot more issues than just this. Anyway, hint for your problem: Your first if statement always returns true. If empty or length over zero = always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Intially check if there is a value. If not return and stop further execution.
- If there's a value check if it is a number or not. return false if not.
- If it is a number check if it has got 10 digits. return false if not.

```
function CheckPhone() {
    let x = document.getElementById("phone").value.trim();
    document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = "";

    // when there is no value entered in the field
    // return true if there is no value in the field
    if ( x == "" ) {
        return true;
    }

    // check if the value is a number
    if ( !isNaN(parseInt(x)) ) {

        // when x is a number
        // check if the number has got 10 digits
        if ( x.length != 10 ) {

            // when number of digits of x is not equal to 10
            document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = "your phone number includes 10 numbers";
            return false;
        } else {

            // when number of digits of x is equal to 10
            return true;
        }

    } else {

        // when x is not a number
        document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Red'>your phone number can only contain numbers</span>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comments, your approach to this problem will cause a lot more issues when it comes to international and/or service numbers. A better approach would be to use regular expressions. Keep in mind though that there isn't a "perfect" approach to this.

The following code allows you to define the minimum and maximum length if you desire to do so anyway, but it's not required (if you want to play it safe):

```
function CheckPhone(str, min = 1, max = 100) {
    // If no phone number given, just return valid
    if(str.length < 1){
        return "valid";
    }

    // Reasonably safe regular expression for phone numbers
    var regex = new RegExp(/^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/, 'g');

    // Check for expected length
    if(str.length < min || str.length > max) {
        return "Your phone number should be between "+min+" and "+max+" characters long.";
    }

    // Check for valid phone number
    if(regex.test(str)) {
        return "valid";
    } else {
        return "Your phone number does not appear to be valid";
    }
}

var result = CheckPhone("+001234567890", 5, 15); // Minimum 5, maximum 15 characters
var example = CheckPhone("+001234567890"); // No minimum or maximum length given

if(result != "valid"){
    document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = result;
} else {
    // valid number given, handle accordingly
}
```

Comment: gotcha, will try this first (and edit accordingly to my needs)

Comment: @kfirezer I wonder why you accept another answer when you're going to use mine though? Aside from upvoting / accepting someone's answer being a way of showing your appreciation for the time spend on helping you out, it's also listed as the best solution for future visitors with the same kind of problem. I don't care for the rep, but I do care about this website remaining a reliable resource for those in need :)

Comment: this ended up not working for some reason, but another one worked, Ill 'V' the one that did the job

Comment: @kfirezer That's quite alright. If you have a moment though, please do explain what didn't work. If something's wrong with my code, I'd love to improve it anyway for others

Comment: sure. I'm dealing with a port problem atm, will do so soon.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of refactoring things are clearer.

```js
function SetError(text = "") {
  document.getElementById("errorPhone").innerHTML = text;
}

function IsNumeric(text) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(text)
}

function CheckPhone() {
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        
        if(!phone || !phone.length) {
          return false;
        }
        
        if(phone.length === 10) {
          SetError("your phone number includes 10 numbers");
          return false
        }
        
        if(!IsNumeric(phone)) {
          SetError("<span style='color:Red'>your phone number can only contain numbers</span>");
          return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
console.log(CheckPhone())
```

```css
#errorPhone {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="phone" id="phone" value="1234567890"/>
<div id="errorPhone"></div>
```

I think it is a good foundation and you can add some functionalities to it